# TypeError: this._headers.getAll is not a function

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js, I am using Prisma and able to get data from db but I have a problem that my request got stalled:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/users/, this may result in stalled requests.

My code is below:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async function GET(request: Request) {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  console.log(users);
  // return NextResponse.next();
}
```

When I uncomment `NextResponse.next();` then I got error:

> TypeError: this._headers.getAll is not a function

[image]

Please note that I am using API Routes.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API route should return a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), and you by calling `NextResponse.next()`, you are not doing that.

If you are using the [page](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, here is how you would do:

```typescript
// pages/api/users.js

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  console.log(users);
  res.status(200).json(users);
}
```

And if you using the [app](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router:

```typescript
// app/api/users/route.ts

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async function GET(request: Request) {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  console.log(users);
  return NextResponse.json(users);
}
```

Comment: but after using .json it gives another error. TypeError: this._headers.getAll is not a function

Comment: I have updated the question with image of error.

Comment: @عثمانغني you are using the `pages` router, so do as I did in my first snippet.

Comment: basically i got confused between app & pages router. Thanks for update.